# I want to send one of the zip folder which consisit of 8 to 10 files, attaching via e-mail using Linux command

Tags: email, mailx

I tried with this command but no luck.

```
echo 'These are contents of my mail' | mailx -s 'This is my email subject' -a /home/user/Desktop/data.zip mail_id@example.com
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What were the results?

Comment: did not display any reults either the error, but did not receive mail

Comment: I also tried as below, does not give any error either it sends the report                   
 ( echo "Hi,\nPlease find attached , the report of script \nThank You";uuencode Mahi.zip Mahireport.zip ) | mail -s "these are the script - Report" -r  mail_id@example.com

Comment: These would all be excellent *edits* to your question.

Answer (score 0):

From the manpage:

```
   -A, --attach=FILE
          attach FILE

   -a, --append=HEADER: VALUE append given header to the message being sent
```

So you want `-A`, not `-a`.
Surprising no errormessage was produced for the malformed header; here it produces:

```
mailx: Invalid header: invalid_header
```

Comment: When i use -A i get error as "Account testfile.zip does not exist.", but i have the zip file.                                                                  
                                                                                                                         
echo 'These are contents of my mail' | mailx -s 'This is my email subject' -A testfile.zip user@in.example.com
Account testfile.zip does not exist.

Comment: Looks like you're using a different `mailx` than i am. Mine is from the (debian) package `mailutis`.